# Listen TCP and receive data

Tags: php, sockets, hl7

I have an HL7 machine that sends data via TCP on a specified port. I want to continuously listen on that port and display any data received on the screen.

I have this which creates a connection but in my scenario, connection is created by the HL7 machine which then starts sending.

```
// host and port to connect to
$host = "localhost";
$port = 9876;
// connect to the port
$fp = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr);


set_time_limit(0);

// if connection not successfull, display error
if (!$fp)
{
die("Error: Could not open socket for connection!");
}
else
{
    // connection successfull, listen for data (1024 bytes by default)
    $got = fgets($fp);

    // display the data
    echo $got;
}

fclose($fp);
```

Comment: You're probably looking for [`socket_listen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-listen.php)

Answer (score 0):

You should wait (block) for a socket connection from the HL7 machine. When a connection is received you should process the data then wait for another connection.

If several connections are made at once and your processing of the HL7 message takes a bit of time, it may be wise to process the message/data from the socket in a new thread.

```
<?php
$condition = true;
$socket = socket_create_listen(port);
socket_set_block($socket);
while (condition) {
    socket_accept($socket);

    // read data from socket
    // condition to break from listening
}

?>
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-set-block.php